# How to iterate through my array within a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, hash

Firstly, I am hoping my understanding is correct and I do in fact have a an array within my hash.

I've gotten so far but cant seem to iterate through each hash and its array. What I would like to do is have each tournament grouped by date (year only) and have all its tournaments listed underneath.

So far my logic is

**Controller**

```
@tournaments = Tournament.all
@tournament_year = @tournaments.group_by {|y| y.tourn_date.year}
```

**View**

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
  <% @tournament_year.each do |y, t| %>
    <li><%= y %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**hash**

```
{2014=>[#<Tournament id: 3, name: "WTS ", tourn_date: "2014-04-26", tourn_location: "Cardiff", created_at: "2014-04-26 14:57:21", updated_at: "2014-04-26 14:57:21">, #<Tournament id: 4, name: "CTS Nottingham", tourn_date: "2014-05-26", tourn_location: "Nottingham", created_at: "2014-04-26 14:57:39", updated_at: "2014-04-26 14:57:48">]}
```

My desired output would be below

```
<h3>2014</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Tournament Name 1</li>
  <li>Tournament Name 2</li>
</ul>

<h3>2013</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Tournament Name 1</li>
  <li>Tournament Name 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your view as below:

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
  <% @tournament_year.each do |y, t| %>
    <h3><%= y %></h3>
    <ul>
    <% t.each_with_index do |tournament, i| %>
      <li><%= tournament.name %> <%= i %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1. However, I don't think 1 from `Tournament Name 1` is an index. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse from the OPs question it looks like an index

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
<% @tournament_year.each do |y, t| %>
  <h3> <%= y %></h3>
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <% t.each do |tournament| %>
      <li><%= "#{tournament.to_s}" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

where

```
#app/models/tournament.rb

def to_s
  "#{name} #{id}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive just come up with this solution as an example, seems to work, can anyone see any reason why this would be incorrect?

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
  <%= @tournament_year.each do |y, t| %>
    <li><%= y %></li>
      <%= @tournament_year[y].each do |x| %>
        <li><%= x.name %></li>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: `tournament[y]` is `t` so you should use t. the html is different from the one specified in the question.